# Swift: Calculate trajectory of node with applied impulse

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, physics

I want to calculate the trajectory of a `SKSpriteNode` after an impulse is applied to it. I have 12 balls and I want to put them at the positions that the ball will be after it is launched. I am using the equation `(t)=₀+t(₀+½Δt)+½t²`

The impulse I apply to the node is based on the length that the user drags on the screen.

This is what I have tried:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            startPositionDrag = location
        }
    }
```

In `touchesMoved` I update the trajectory nodes to show where the node will go if launched at that position.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   for touch in touches{

        movedLocation = touch.location(in: self) 

        calculateTrajectoryy(velocityY: (startPositionDrag.y - movedLocation.y), velocityX: (startPositionDrag.x - movedLocation.x))

     }
```

This is where I use the equation. I have an array of 12 balls. I use `i` as time because I want to put each ball at the position of where the node will be after `i` seconds.

```
func calculateTrajectoryy(velocityY: CGFloat, velocityX: CGFloat){

        for i in 0...12{

            let time = CGFloat(i)
            let accelerationX = CGFloat(0)
            let accelerationY = CGFloat(-9.8)
            var x = CGFloat()
            var y = CGFloat()

            // (t)=₀+t(₀+½Δt)+½t²
            x = ball.position.x + time * (velocityX + 0.5 * time * accelerationX) + 0.5 * time * time * accelerationX

            y = ball.position.y + time * (velocityY + 0.5 * time * accelerationY) + 0.5 * time * time * accelerationY

            arrray[i].position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        }
    }
```

Finally in `touchesEnded`, when the user lets go of the drag, the node will have an impulse applied and it should follow exactly the path of balls created.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            let location = touch.location(in: self)

               ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:(startPositionDrag.x - endPositionDrag.x), dy:(startPositionDrag.y - endPositionDrag.y))

            }
        }
    }
```

The ball does not follow the arc created by the balls. The ball shoots a small bit, while the arc of balls is big and long. I think this might have to do with conversion of units. The equation uses the velocity values as meters per second,  while the position dragged back is a `CGFloat`. Meters would be longer that a `CGFloat`, so the predicted trajectory would be longer. How would I be able to convert the trajectory to work with pixels or `CGFloat`s? Is there a pixels to meter ratio that I could divide by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(an answer from standpoint of physics, I'm not an expert in either swift or sprite-kit)

The choice of 'units' (and what physical distance a point represents) is entirely yours, the math that you have up to the point where you call `applyImpulse()` is consistent in assuming 1point = 1meter. This may or may not be what you want, but it is an OK choice - BTW, the only thing that (sort-of) fixes a point to a real-world meter in your code is the gravity value of 9.8, otherwise you can just call them point with no change in real meaning - the physics engine doesn't really care.

The consecutive ball positions that you put into array[] in your code are made on the assumption that the launched ball will cover the distance from start_of_drag to end_of_drag in one second (because you simply use the distance as a velocity value, i.e., 1m becomes 1m/sec, 2m = 2m/s, etc.).
(NOTE I don't quite know how the 12-point predicted path worked correctly in your case, because to get a vector pointing in the direction of the drag you'd normally do `end_drag - start_drag`, while your code does `start - end`)

The problem you have likely has to do with the fact that `applyImpulse` expects values in units of newton*second (and the velocity change will depend on the ball's mass: delta-V = impulse / mass), while you call the function with those same "distance-that-became-velocity" units.

If the ball is always stationary prior to the drag, and you want it to start instantly going somewhere at a chosen velocity, it might be easier to simply assign its velocity to the desired value and let it fly, rather than try to use `applyImpulse`, e.g.:

(edit: as @knight0fdragon pointed out, SK's units of distance are points, but velocity is measured in units of an abstract 'meter' = 150pt/sec, so if you did the math in points and points/sec so far, you'd have to scale the velocity before modifying a physicsBody vector: divide it by 150.0).

```
ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx:velocityX, dy:velocityY)
```

If the ball already has some velocity and you want to modify it by some amount (which is expressed in velocity units for you rather than in N*m) and disregarding the mass, add that velocity change to the ball's current velocity.

Comment: in sprite kit, 150 points is 1 meter, so a velocity of 1,0 would move the ball 150 points in 1 second

Comment: @Leo K, Thank you for your response, but first, applyImpulse is actually velocity not a force. Second, I divided the value by 150 and it is way to small now, it seems like 150 is too big of a number.

Comment: 'is actually velocity, not a force'. I didn't say it were a force, it is impulse - but that's NOT the same thing as velocity. See here, it says 
 how the impulse is measured - surely not m/s: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519900-applyimpulse

Comment: divide by 150 if you're applying the velocity change to the x.velocity property directly (as I suggested), not if you're using `applyImpulse`. If you use the latter, but have a *velocity change* at hand, you'd have to compute what impulse is needed to achieve that change - only to have SK apply the reverse math to convert that back to velocity change when you call `applyImpulse`.

Comment: I changed your pixels to points,  since these are 2 different units.  In sprite kit, 1 point could equal 'X' pixels depending on retina and the scale mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show how I applied Leo K's answer to the code.

Somehow I used the 150 from the pixels to inch ratio and turned it to 1.5, divided by 1.5 for the trajectory and multiplied by it for the impulse. It almost exactly predicts the path of the node.

```
    calculateTrajectoryy(velocityY: (startPositionDrag.y - movedLocation.y) / 1.5, velocityX: (startPositionDrag.x - movedLocation.x) / 1.5)

    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:(startPositionDrag.x - endPositionDrag.x) * 1.5, dy:(startPositionDrag.y - endPositionDrag.y) * 1.5)
```

Comment: What is the mass of your ball?  Is it 100KG?

Comment: the mass doesn't matter I am only dealing with velocity, but it is 0.24999912083149 units

Comment: You are not dealing with velocity, impulse is a force, so mass does matter

Comment: The only difference between applyimpulse and applyforce is applyimpulse happens immediately, and applyforce happens during the physics phase (applyforce also has a bug that the units are in points and not meters,  not sure if this got fixed yet)

Comment: the other thing is apply force is also 1/60th of a second (Assuming your FPS is 60) where as apply impulse immediately applies the full second.  If you are curious to find out more, SKPhysics is a derivative of Box2D, so you can look at Box2D to figure out things they are doing.